# Invoking function in calling script from library

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a Google Spreadsheet with custom menu-options to be used by multiple people. I've put the code behind the menu options in a separate Library which is consumed as a resource by the script in the sheet. The script in the sheet is essentially dumb with callbacks to the Library to handle all the logic. This is done so that the code can be maintained in one central place.

Now, my problem is that the Library needs a way to store some sheet-specific data somewhere, which should not be shared between any two instances of the sheet.

Some things I've tried or I'm thinking of trying:

1. Create getter/setter functions in the script in the sheet, and try calling these from the library. However, the functions in the calling script don't seem to be visible to the Library code.
2. Globals in the Library - I'm wary of using this because I suspect the globals will be held in the context of the Library and therefore will cause all sorts of concurrency problems
3. User Properties - What if the same user has two copies of the same tool open? Will the User Properties with the same name collide?

Would appreciate any ideas/suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it on scripdDb of the library (or pass the db to the library in a param if you want to store it on each dummy script instead).
Two of your db object properties would be the user email and the spreadsheet id.

Comment: I like the idea of passing a ScriptDB instance back to the Library. But two follow-up questions:  
  
1. How can I get the ScriptDB instance back from the dummy script on subsequent runs of the library functions? Or do I have to just pass the ScriptDB instance from the dummy script on every placeholder function callback?  
  
2. Won't storing in ScriptDB also entail some kind of purge/archival logic as well? I'm sure I can come up with something but would rather avoid the complexity if I can help it.

Comment: 1: yes you need to pass it every time. 2. Yes you need to purge it to avoid fhe db size limits which vary on the type of account (gmail, gapps free or biz)